# How to check the content of a file if it has changes before processing it on a job using the spring batch framework

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

How to check the content of a file if it has changes before processing it on a job using the spring batch framework. My idea is to compare it on the existing database where I wrote that file content (the previous content of the file). To avoid processing it again if there is no changes on the content of that file. I am new in using spring batch framework . Can you give me some idea or sample codes to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Spring Integration Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

You can use a file inbound channel adapter, configured with a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. If the modified time on the file changes, the file will be resent to the message channel.

Then, using the Spring Batch Integration components (e.g. `JobLaunchingGateway`) to launch your batch job to process the file.

You need to be careful, though, to not pick up the file while it is in the process of being modified. It's generally better to remove or rename the file after processing and have the writer create a temporary file and rename it to the final file name after writing. This will avoid the problem of the adapter "seeing" a partially updated file.